# How to get the IE11.0.18 version? Currently I have IE11.0.21

Tags: internet-explorer

I have Internet Exlporer 11.0.21, I want to degrade the version to IE11.0.18/IE11.0.19? But in the available updates only 11.0.21 is available?
Can anyone please help how to update to this version 11.0.18 or 11.0.19?